# ssh publickey permission denied only from a particular host

Tags: ssh

Our lab's compute cluster has a two-interface 'gateway' machine which we use to access the cluster nodes.  Call this gateway1.publicdomain.com.  Normally I access this machine from my laptop, laptop.anydomain.com like this:

ssh joe@gateway1.publicdomain.com

I have set up a public key in .ssh/id_rsa.pub on laptop, and copied that to .ssh/authorized_keys on gateway1.  Ordinarily this works fine.

Today I am using a public access point rather than my usual work connection.  When I do

ssh joe@gateway1.publicdomain.com

I get the response:

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).

Apparently it won't accept my id_rsa credentials (Problem 1) and I am not prompted for a password (Problem 2) even though ordinarily when I log in from a previously  unknown host I am prompted for a password.

I am still able to ssh to gateway1 from another machine (call it otherhost.otherdomain.com) without problem, either with password or (after setting up the relevant id_rsa* files) with publickey authentication.  I can also log into otherhost itself using publickey credentials from laptop, so I know there's nothing fundamentally broken about laptop's ssh setup.

Finally, even when I delete my public key form .ssh/authorized_keys on gateway1, I still get the same "Permission denied" message and no password prompt.

So I guess my question is, what can cause gateway1 to reject my publickey credentials from my laptop, and prevent password login, but not from another host?  I have confirmed that the id_rsa.pub on laptop and authorized_keys on gateway1 are in sync.

EDIT: I haven't been able to duplicate the problem since I originally posted, because it only happened when I was connected to a particular wireless access point (not belonging to me or to my lab).  I still don't know how this could occur.

Answer (score 2):

Someone might be using the `AllowUsers` directive in the configuration of the server, or you might be using the wrong version of the SSH protocol.

Try adding -v (or two of them) to step up the verbosity; you might find something more helpful than simply denied.

Similarly, you can initiate ssh without a key exchange, rather than removing it on the server's authorized keys list.  Read about it on [the man page for ssh](http://www.openssh.org/manual.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running debian? Might this be caused by blacklisted SSH keys?